# WHMCS domain transfer external api returns domain not found error always

Tags: wordpress, api, whmcs

I have installed and configured the WHMCS in my wordpress site.I want to transfer a domain using the api functionality "domaintransfer" as action name.But the response from the api always return "Domain not found" error.
I am passing the following parameters

1. action : domaintransfer
2. domain : domain name entered(like xxx.com)

Answer (score 0):

You use [domaintransfer](http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Transfer_Domain) API function if the domain already in the database, but if you're transferring a domain from another company to yours you should use [addorder](http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Add_Order) and set `domaintype` parameter to transfer.